# Cant get pycharm to work get ERROR: The executable C:\Users\tedpo\PycharmProjects\untitled4\venv\Scripts\python.exe is not functioning

Tags: python-2.7

I cannot get pycharm to work.

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: The executable C:\Users\tedpo\PycharmProjects\untitled4\venv\Scripts\python.exe is not functioning
```

The log box indicated this error may be because it was installed as one user.  I re-installed it, but did not see a dialog asking me if I wanted it this user or all users.

The log box has:

```
Using base prefix 'C:\\Python34'
New python executable in C:\Users\tedpo\PycharmProjects\untitled4\venv\Scripts\python.exe
ERROR: The executable C:\Users\tedpo\PycharmProjects\untitled4\venv\Scripts\python.exe is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is 'c:\\users\\tedpo\\appdata\\local\\temp\\tmp8dhe0ylepycharm-management\\virtualenv-15.1.0' (should be 'c:\\users\\tedpo\\pycharmprojects\\untitled4\\venv')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
Note: some Windows users have reported this error when they installed Python for "Only this user" or have multiple versions of Python installed. Copying the appropriate PythonXX.dll to the virtualenv Scripts/ directory may fix this problem.
```

Comment: Have you tried what the Note says?

Answer (score 1):

Sorted this out by removing all python programs (I had multiple versions installed) and then reinstalling.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but I fixed it after deleting every older version of python I had and reinstalled pycharm.